# The requested file was not found./android_assets/www/pica.html

Tags: android

I am fresher in this field and while trying to add html page in eclipse and run it on AVD its showing error on AVD "the requested file was not found./android_assets/www/pica.html(no such file or directory)(file:///android_assets/www/pica.html)"

my code is as below

```
import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_assets/www/pica.html");
    }
```

Its showing error,

```
ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.projectexample/.MainActivity }
ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
and ERROR: Plugin.xml is missing. Add res/xml/plugins.xml to your program.
```

Answer (score 1):

Well it would seem the file you are linking to is in a different location or has a different name.

Your project structure should be something like this:

```
- Project Root Folder  
          - src    
            ... java source files  
          - res    
            ... resources  
          - assets    
             - www  
               - pica.html
```

And as for the second problem with the plugin.xml: Just create the xml manually in the folder res/xml.

Comment: Thanks but my project structure is like                              - src    
      ... java source files                                          - assets    
             - www  
               - pica.html                                            - res    
            ... resources                                             Then what changes i need to do??     Do i need to give the whole path??   can you give me an example about how to write a path??

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer, because its really new thing for me.

Comment: Please edot your project structure into your question, and generally if your structe is a little different it's ok too. The important part are the assets, it has to be assets - www - pica.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `android_asset` instead of `android_assets` in the URI (note the missing `s`):

```
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/pica.html");
```